# Laravel 5 - Using php file in public folder as view and pass json

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, laravel-5

I'm making a back-end API with Laravel 5.3

One of the API is this in OnaController which will return Json format :

```
public function index()
{
    $limit = Input::get('limit') ?: 10;

    if ($limit < 1 or $limit > 100) {
        $limit = 10;
    }

    $ona_datas = Onaio::where('status', '<>', 4)->paginate($limit);

    return $this->respondWithPagination(
                $ona_datas,
                $this->onaTransformer->transformCollection($ona_datas->all())
            );
}
```

the front-end file named as **ona_list.php** placed in the public folder **(/public)**

my question is how to make the file as a view and then passing the json to it?
i want to open the file with the same URL **(my_website.com/ona)**

here are what i've tried so far:

1. `return view(asset('ona_list.php')` but it threw `InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [http:..localhost:8000.ona_list.php] not found.`
2. `return redirect(asset('ona_list.php'))
   ->with(json_decode($this->respondWithPagination($ona_datas, 
   $this->onaTransformer->transformCollection(
   $ona_datas->all()))));` 
   but the URL changed into my_website.com\ona_list.php and the data isn't showing

Comment: What does your routes/api.php look like?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you place ona_list.php in public folder? All requests are redirected by default to index.php

What you can do is, define a new route as the following `Route::get('ona', 'OnaController@index');` and access it as your_website.com/ona

in `OnaController@index` make sure you return json as the following

`class OnaController extends Controller
{
    ...
    return response()->json($ona_dates);
}`